# How do you open the Developer's Console on Chrome on an iPad?

Tags: google-chrome, ipad

[This answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/121672/28379) says that you need to activate the Developer's Console to do what it says. However, I need to do this on an iPad with Chrome installed. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This is off-topic here, might be better suited to apple.SE

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging would be of some help.

Comment: Also be sure to check out mobile device emulation in Chrome 32+ via http://www.sitepoint.com/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that in Chrome on an iPad. Since Mobile Chrome is, well, *mobile*, it is a *stripped-down* version of Chrome.

That means no Dev tools.

I'm not sure if this will do what you want (you probably want to see some code), but Mobile Safari has some dev-ish tools. The switch to enable them is found under Settings > Safari.

Chrome 32+ for the desktop now has [mobile device emulation](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/), which is useful for debugging things via the console, such as touch events that don't necessarily exist on the desktop.

Comment: Unfortunately, my save is in Chrome. Unless I can go into my iPad's hard drive and pull out what I need from there.

Comment: @jeff I don't believe that Mobile Chrome contains any Dev tools. Sorry :)

Comment: Dang. Can I install an extension? If not, no big deal either. I'll just start over.

Comment: @jeff Last time I checked, Mobile Chrome wasn't receptive to extensions. In fact, Apple has a rule that apps can't download new code. Extensions are code, therefore...

Comment: you could always use a bookmarklet

Comment: you CAN view the js console; https://blog.chromium.org/2019/03/debugging-websites-in-chrome-for-ios.html